# how to customize PropertyInfo[] object in PropertyGrid C#

Tags: c#, propertygrid, icustomtypedescriptor

i have a class that is loaded dynamically and i don't know in advance how many (or of what type) properties it contains.
i would like to load all its properties into a PropertyGrid in a way that it would display as it displays a regular class.

for instance, if this is my class:

```
class TestPropertyObject
{
    [Category("Names")]
    [Description("Enter your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Category("Numbers")]
    [Description("Enter your number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

and i use reflection to generate an object and get its properties:

```
PropertyInfo[] info = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
```

how do i display the properties in the PropertyGrid?
i already ready many times this article 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert
but i just can't seem to get it to work.

some guidance would be very much appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution, you just need the instance of the class.

```
        var OptionsPropertyGrid = new PropertyGrid();
        OptionsPropertyGrid.Size = new Size(300, 250);

        this.Controls.Add(OptionsPropertyGrid);

        TestPropertyObject appset = new TestPropertyObject();
        OptionsPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = appset;
```

This sample is assuming that you class's property is decorated with Category/description.
let me know if I have misunderstood it.

Or by using dynamic object

```
        var OptionsPropertyGrid = new PropertyGrid();
        OptionsPropertyGrid.Size = new Size(300, 250);

        this.Controls.Add(OptionsPropertyGrid);
        this.Text = "Options Dialog";
        string classname = "WindowsFormsApplication1.TestPropertyObject";
        var type1 = Type.GetType(classname);
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type1);
        OptionsPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = obj;
```

Make sure you can be able get the namespace of the class.

Comment: this won't work because i'm creating an object of TestPropertyObject via reflection. actually, i will know what class and what\how many properties it has only in runtime.